# Union of two different shapefiles GDAL

Tags: shapefile, union

With Python 3 and GDAL package, I am trying to merge two shapefiles that come with databases.

They come with the following files:

- grade_id14.cpg
- grade_id14.dbf
- grade_id14.prj
- grade_id14.sbn
- grade_id14.sbx
- grade_id14.shp

My code goes as it follows :

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

test = ogr.Open('grade_id13.shp')
test2 = ogr.Open('grade_id14.shp')

lyr1 = test.GetLayer()
lyr2 = test2.GetLayer()
unionc = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
print(lyr1.GetGeomType()) #it shows 3


for feat in range(lyr1.GetFeatureCount()):
    fit1= lyr1.GetFeature(feat)
    geom1= fit1.GetGeometryRef()
    unionc.AddGeometry(geom1)

for feat2 in range(lyr2.GetFeatureCount()):
    fit2= lyr2.GetFeature(feat)
    geom2= fit2.GetGeometryRef()
    unionc.AddGeometry(geom2)

union= unionc.UnionCascaded()

unionTest = geom2.Union(geom1)

# Create datasource.
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
try:
    ds_out = driver.CreateDataSource('test.shp')
except:
    raise Exception("File already exists.")

# I believe here is the problem, when I try to get the layers from the united polygon,
# doesnt work
lyrU = union.GetLayer()


srs = lyrU.GetSpatialRef()
geom_type = lyrU.GetGeomType()

# Create empty layer.
layer_out = ds_out.CreateLayer(name = 'testLayer', srs = srs, geom_type = geom_type)

# Copy fields <-- not required.
layer_defn = lyrU.GetLayerDefn()
n_fields = layer_defn.GetFieldCount()
for i in range(n_fields):
    layer_out.CreateField(layer_defn.GetFieldDefn(i))
```

My ultimate objective is to unify several shapefiles.

Comment: A bit more info is probably required to resolve this.  When you say it doesn't work, do you get an empty union, does it fail with an error or something else?  If you are getting the error it would be good if you could provide the output.

Comment: @EnE_ It says lyrU doesn't have get attribute to get the layer. I ended up using geopandas and worked out, actually.